# Continue countdown timer when app is runing in background

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to implement the app using OC timer that can also continue to run in the background.
I want to realize the countdown function, such as 03:10:39...03:10:38 runs in the background

Comment: What are you looking to do? Perform an action at the end of the countdown (i.e. at a specific point in time)? Display the amount of time left (i.e. update UI every second for the duration of the countdown)? Both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to continue the countdown operation when your app is in background. You can always calculate the end time first. And when the app back to foreground, just update the UI. (end time - current time)